# Issue with mysql_real_escape_string

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query:
`SELECT * FROM ships WHERE shipCode="SP"`
`SELECT * FROM ships WHERE shipCode=\"SP\"`

The first works fine, the second which is the result of calling mysql_real_escape_string on the first string, doesn't work and gives the useless error message `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\"SP\"' at line 1`

What's wrong with it?

shipCode is a VARCHAR(2)

Comment: Post your PHP code.  MySQL may accept single quoted strings, depending how it is configured, but single quotes are standard SQL.

Comment: You shouldn't be using mysql_* functions anymore.  Use the mysqli or Pdo class instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not supposed to call `mysql_real_escape_string` on *the whole* string. You use it only on the *values* you're concatenating into your query.

**Wrong:**

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM ships WHERE shipCode="' . $var . '"';
$query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
```

Right:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM ships WHERE shipCode="' . mysql_real_escape_string($var) . '"';
```

Even better: [Prepared statements.](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score 0):

you need to have valid connection with mysql set up before you use mysql_real_escape string . do it like this

```
$attr="sp";
Select * from ships where shipcode = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($attr) . "';
```